Jira-python changelog for more than 100 changelog items
Trying to fetch the changelog for a JIRA using python lib. To get that I'm using the search_issues method with a param expand = 'changelog'. I'm only receiving top 100 changes though I have 500+ changelog items.
res = self.jira.search_issues( 
 jql,
 maxResults=max_results, 
 startAt=start, 
 fields=fields, 
 json_result=False, 
 expand="changelog" 
)

I tried this with each individual issue using issue() method as well. But same problem there.
Here I found one answer to use expand = ['changelog'], but that didn't work either. I don't want to use the REST API. Is there a solution to get that done.
